# Saving Models in Session

Tags: java, session, model, wicket

I use Martijn's approach for an `EntityModel`: http://wicketinaction.com/2008/09/building-a-smart-entitymodel/

I use the `EntityModel` for storing data in my custom wicket session.

```
 private IModel<Order> order;
 private IModel<User> user;
```

It's set like this:

```
getSession().setOrder(new EntityModel<Order>(order));
```

My application is a wizard-like order transaction with about 7, 8 connected pages. In some of the pages a bunch of objects get persisted, but not all. So the use of `EntityModel` allows me to only store the unpersisted objects in the session while the persisted objects just hold the unique ID.

The problem is that the `detach()` method is never called because the model isn't in any component.

- Is saving models into the session the right approach?
- Do I have to call `detach()` manually in the session on each model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally easier to keep your models attached to components so that Wicket just does the detach for you, but for models that are shared between many pages, you can certainly do it this way.  This is how the user model is handled in databinder's [AuthDataSession](http://databinder.net/javadoc/net/databinder/auth/hib/AuthDataSession.html), and I've used the tactic for other heavily shared models.

If you're storing stuff in your custom extension of Wicket's WebSession, you can override the `detach()` method of Wicket's [Session](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/Session.html) class in your extension:

```
@Override
protected void detach() {

    // detach the models you're holding in your custom session 
    // by calling all their detach methods.

    super.detach();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, storing models in session isn't a good idea. The Wicket session is shared by different requests with separate life-cycles and thus by different threads. Sharing objects this way will cause all kinds of subtle problems.

Instead, you should only share the object's ID and create a new model for every request. You could even create multiple models and rely on your session cache and second level cache to absorb any performance issues.

Alternatively, you could store data as meta data of the RequestCycle. If you want, you could use my [RequestCycleCache](https://github.com/molindo/molindo-wicket-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/at/molindo/wicketutils/utils/RequestCycleCache.java) to do so.

```
public User getUser() {
  return RequestCycleCache.getOrCreate(USER_KEY, _userId, FETCH_USER_FUNCTION);
}
```

Comment: I thought a session is a user-bound instance with no sharing at all. About just saving the ID of the object: That's what the `EntityModel` also does if the object has an ID. Your `RequestCycleCache` looks interesting but kinda seems like a (undesired) workaround...

Comment: a Wicket session is bound to a user session, yes. But nobody stops a user from submitting concurrent requests. Therefore, you'll have to make sure that instances of User are bound to a request cycle (or request, page or component) and not to the session. I know that Martijn's EntityModel stores the ID itself, nevertheless models aren't meant to be used at session scope.